# How do I use tag-manager with simple-form and using HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tags, haml

### Env

- RoR 4.0.4
- [tag-manager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3)
- [simple-form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)
- HAML
- Bootstrap

### My current code

```
= simple_form_for(@project,
  html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }, wrapper: :horizontal_form, wrapper_mappings: { check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, file: :horizontal_file_input, boolean: :horizontal_boolean}) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.hidden_field :owner_id
    = f.label "#{current_user.id}" 
    = f.input :title

    %input#tm-language.tm-input{:name => "language", :placeholder => "Programming language", :type => "text"}/

  .form-actions{style: "text-align:right;"}
    = f.button :submit

:javascript
  jQuery(".tm-input").tagsManager();
```

I'd like to be able to change this

```
    %input#tm-language.tm-input{:name => "language", :placeholder => "Programming language", :type => "text"}/
```

in to something that looks rather like this:

```
    = f.input.tm-input :language, placeholder: "Programming language"
```

only the later isn't the right syntax.

Tried this:

```
= f.input.tm-input :language, :input_html => { :placeholder => 'Programming Language' }
```

and got this error

```
SyntaxError at /projects/new
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...true_false(( f.input.tm-input :language, :input_html => { :p...
...       

                    ^
```

Comment: Try `= f.input.tm-input :language,  :input_html => { :placeholder => 'Programming Language' }`

Comment: Didn't work, I am getting this error SyntaxError at /projects/new
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...true_false(( f.input.tm-input :language, :input_html => { :p...
...                               ^

Comment: Remove the class `tm-input` and add it as `:class => "tm-input" . `= f.input :language, :input_html => { :class => "tm-input", :placeholder => 'Programming Language' }`. I guess this should solve it.